# How to free an object inside its event handler?

Tags: delphi

I have TMyClass, a class derived from TObject. It has a TTimer. Every few minutes, from Timer.OnTimer I check a web page. When the web page changes, I am done and I want to free MyClass. How do I free it?

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502565/how-to-free-control-inside-its-event-handler) one BUT my 'control' is not a TControl. It is descendent of TObject. So, Messages won't work.
Obviously, the solution will be to derive my class from TControl or higher. But let's say I don't want to do that. What would be the solution in this case?

Comment: Wait, so you are not holding references to those objects (you are leaking them when the app. terminates) ? If you do, and the object releases itself *from inside* then the reference becomes a dangling pointer after that (on which you then try to call `Free`). You should consider some sort of object manager and ask that manager to release the object (and remove it from its reference collection).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To receive messages you need to have window handle. You can allocate one using [AllocateHWnd](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_AllocateHWnd.html), something like

```
type
  TMyClass = class(TObject)
  private
    FHandle: HWND;
    procedure MyWndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
  public
    constructor Create; virtual;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

constructor TMyClass.Create();
begin
  inherited Create();
  FHandle := AllocateHWnd(myWndProc);
end;

destructor TMyClass.Destroy;
begin
  DeallocateHWnd(FHandle);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyClass.MyWndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  case Msg.Msg of
    CM_RELEASE: begin
       Free;
    end;
    else Msg.Result := DefWindowProc(FHandle, Msg.Msg, Msg.WParam, Msg.LParam);
  end;
end;
```

Now you can post messages to the object using the `FHandle` as demonstrated in the post youre reffering to.

Comment: Do beware though that `TMyClass.Create` can only be called from the main thread because `AllocateHWnd` has that restriction. Using a bespoke version of `AllocateHWnd` would solve that. Of course, it's likely the case that you only want methods of `TMyClass` to be called on the main thread, so this is almost surely not an issue that concerns you.

Comment: ...and you'll produce a dangling pointer. This answer is correct, the idea of self destructive (non interfaced) objects is bad.

Answer (score 6):

The basic idea behind using a message is correct: ensure that the object gets freed at a later point, after whatever code is currently calling it is finished.

A few years ago, I wrote a [Delayed Action](http://tech.turbu-rpg.com/454/delayed-action-revisited) unit that gives you a simple way to accomplish this same effect without a TControl.  You just call `DelayExec` and pass an anonymous method to it that will free the object, and it sets up a message internally that makes it happen once the message queue gets pumped.

Comment: As simple as it gets. Flexible and versatile.