# Delphi Firemonkey TButton free

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

I've found something very strange in Delphi 10.1 Firemonkey.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Button1.Free;
end;
```

After this - when I clicked on this button, the form's system icons aren't working! It returns to work only when pressed another button or switched to another window and back again.
Why?
I'm confused...

Comment: See [How to free an object inside its event handler?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29576773/576719). You will have to delay a call to the GUI, where the component is freed. You must not free it in its event handler, since the component is still executing when the event is ready.

Comment: The button is owned by TForm1 and the latter will free the TButton when needed. You really shouldn't free it manually. You could create a button and set the owner to nil if you really wish. Also I'd prefer FreeAndNil but actually it depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Note also that this code won't work at all on ARC-based systems. The button has multiple references by its `Owner` and `Parent`. Calling `Free` will simply assign nil to the `Button1` member of the `TForm1` object, but the button itself will still be alive and visible.

Comment: If you want the button to disappear you could set the Visible property to false instead of freeing it

Comment: I presented my solution - no .Free, but a RemoveObject using object's parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to solve it is:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RemoveObject(Button1);
end;
```

In VCL worked with the .Free, but the FMX works in some different way.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the way (horrible way) arc is made under delphi. Under arc Free do nothing. it's completely stupid but guy at embarcadero seam to like it and after i see people like you who don't understand why their code don't work...

so instead of doing button1.free you need to do button1.disposeOF ... replace all your free by disposeOF and your code will be less buggy under ARC and say thanks to emb

Comment: But there is a memory leak if you don't use any Free or similar method. So Free does something... Of course thanks to emb :) they've made me a lot more creative programmer to "solve around" problems ;)