# Delphi 10.2 Tokyo Firemonkey Multi Device Project ShowModal does not close Form in Android

Tags: android, delphi, modal-dialog, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I'm trying to upgrade my multi device apps from Delphi 10 Seattle to
Delphi 10.2 Tokyo.

Only now i'm experiencing some strange behavior on Android with
ShowModal forms. The form does get the modalresult but does not close the showmodal form. How can I fix this?

Code example below:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  frm_Test: Tfrm_Test;
begin
  inherited;
  frm_Test := Tfrm_Test.Create(nil);
  frm_Test.ShowModal(
    procedure(ModalResult: TModalResult)
    begin
      if ModalResult = mrOk then
      begin
        ShowMessage('Ok'); // This message is shown on top of the form frm_Test
      end;
    end);
end;

procedure Tfrm_Test.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  ShowMessage('frm_Test close'); // This message also get's shown on top of frm_test form
  Action := TCloseAction.caFree; // This does not free the form, form will stay on top of Form1
end;
```

Do I need to Free/Close the form a different way or do I need to set some form properties or something?

**UPDATE**

I've done some other tests and now it seems like using
TCloseAction.caFree does not work on Android to free the form anymore.

My test:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  frm_Test: Tfrm_Test;
begin
  inherited;
  frm_Test := Tfrm_Test.Create(nil);
  frm_Test.Show;
  {*
   * I've also tried using a try finally here and freeing the form inside the finally. This also did not have any effect.
   *}
end;

procedure Tfrm_Test.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := TCloseAction.caFree;
end;

procedure Tfrm_Test.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Close;
end;
```

So how should I close and Free a Form om Delphi 10.2? Strange thing is that
using the the Android hardware back button does close the form and that also calls the Form.Close event.
And using the standard WindowClose action does not work either.

Comment: I think the problem is that you are trying to free the form inside it's event handler see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502565/how-to-free-control-inside-its-event-handler?s=7|3.3023) if you still want to do that

Comment: Have you [read this](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.Forms.TCommonCustomForm.ShowModal), especially the "Caution"?

Comment: Android does not support modal dialogs.

Comment: @LURD but it does support the asynchronous version of `ShowModal()` (Android is the reason why that overload exists in the first place). The dialog is not actually modal, from the OS's perspective.

Comment: @NasreddineAbdelillahGalfout: the code is not freeing the Form inside an event handler. Setting the `Action` parameter to `caFree` in the `OnClose` event is a **delayed** free.  The Form is not actually freed until a later time when it is safe to do so.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, the async ShowModal perhaps was introduced to support modal dialogs in Android, but doc's changed (and evidently code between Tokyo and Seattle) and now says explicitly not to use `ShowModal` (async or not).

Comment: The `FMX.DialogService` and  [FMX.DialogService.Async.TDialogServiceAsync](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.DialogService.Async.TDialogServiceAsync) was introduced in Berlin for platform support of different async dialogs.

Comment: @LURD: those only deal with popup dialogs, like `InputQuery()` and `ShowMessage()`.  They don't deal with modal Forms at all.  AFAIK, the async version of `ShowModal()` still works on Android, despite the warning in the docs.

Comment: @NasreddineAbdelillahGalfout that's not what i'm trying to do. I'm just trying to get showmodal working on Android. Maybe using freeing the form inside event handler is a solution though.

Comment: @TomBrunberg Yes I've seen the caution, but that was also with previous versions I think. And I've also tested this on Delphi 10.1 Berlin and there it still works.

Comment: @RemyLebeau do you know when it is "Safe" to free the form? Can you invoke that in some way?

Comment: @LURD how is this question a duplicate of that? In xe7 it was possible to use showmodal the way i've described in my question.

Comment: @Remi it is "safe" to free a Form when you are not inside one of its methods or events. Using `caFree` in the `OnClose` event invokes a "safe" free by delaying it until control returns to the UI message loop.

Comment: @RemyLebeau but why doesn't that seem to work even in my second test?