# Getting access violation error in FormClose using VCL Themes

Tags: delphi, vcl, vcl-styles

I developed an application in VCL which is using VCL Themes. This application requires TPageControl and inner(child) forms in it.

Each child form has same way in **OnClose**: `Parent.Destroy;`

```
 MsgResp := MessageDlg('Closing info....', mtWarning, [mbYes, mbNo, mbCancel], 0);
  case MsgResp of
    mrYes:
      begin
        DoSomething; {Save something}
        Parent.Destroy;
      end; 
    mrNo:
      begin
        Parent.Destroy;
      end;
    mrCancel:
      begin
        Exit;
      end;
 end;
```

If I set a theme to application like Sapphire Kamri (or something else), I get access violation error in destroying parent component. But if I use default style (Windows), this code works fine.

Comment: As an aside, we seldom call `Destroy` on an object other than `Self`. Instead we use `Free` which first checks whether it not the subject is `nil`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is entirely to be expected. Your code is just as broken without VCL styles, but you get away with it.

The problem is the calls to `Parent.Destroy`. When these occur, the parent is destroyed, and so are all of its children, including the control that owns the code seen in the question. When the call to `Parent.Destroy` returns, execution continues in methods of objects that have been destroyed. That is the source of the runtime error.

You need to schedule the destruction to happen after the `OnClose` event handler has completed. The VCL `Release` method exists for this very purpose.

Comment: As I understand that I shouldn't use `Destroy` for `Self` or `Parent`. What would be the best schedule for destruction?

Comment: You can use `Release` if the parent is a form, otherwise implement yourself with https://stackoverflow.com/a/2502613/505088

Comment: I should handle `Release` for my parent control. Thank you for your help.